# Qt Concurrent: call member function from another class

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11

In Qt Creator, using C++ I have to call the same function from another class for many times. However this slows down the overall performance speed. So in order to do real-time operation, I thought of using multithreading. After some search I found `Qt Concurrent` might help so tried the following steps.

My target function is in this class:

```
Class myClass
{
   public foo(std::vector<float> inputVec, std::string inputStr);
}
```

And in my main class, I do this:

```
std::vector<float> mvec;
// here put some values into mvec;
std::string mstring = "test";

myClass mcl;

QFuture<float> f1 = QtConcurrent::run(mcl.foo(mvec, mstring));
f1.waitForFinished();
```

However, this gives out error saying:

```
no matching function for call to 'run(float)'
'functor' cannot be used as a function
'float' is not a class, struct, or union type
...
```

I also tried to use `std::thread` like this:

```
std::thread t1 = std::thread(mcl.foo, mvec, mstring);
if(t1.joinable()) t1.join();
```

But this throws the following error:

```
invalid use of non-static member function
```

I've tried many example codes online but still confused. How can I make this code to run smoothly and thread safe? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following statement, executes the `foo` method and passes the result of it to the `run` function.

```
QtConcurrent::run(mcl.foo(mvec, mstring));
```

The correct form is:

```
QtConcurrent::run(&mcl, &myClass::foo, mvec, mstring);
```

Also note that calling `f1.waitForFinished();` after that, actually blocks your thread until the `foo` method completes. So you won't gain any advantage of multithreading.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the (member-)function itself (plus the object the member shall relate to), not the result of just calling it. Have a look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html):

> `QtConcurrent::run()` also accepts pointers to member functions. The
>   first argument must be either a const reference or a pointer to an
>   instance of the class. Passing by const reference is useful when
>   calling const member functions; passing by pointer is useful for
>   calling non-const member functions that modify the instance.
>
> For example, calling `QByteArray::split()` (a const member function) in
>   a separate thread is done like this:
>
> ```
> // call 'QList<QByteArray>  QByteArray::split(char sep) const' in a
> separate thread QByteArray bytearray = "hello world";
> QFuture<QList<QByteArray> > future = QtConcurrent::run(bytearray, &QByteArray::split, ',');
> ... 
> QList<QByteArray> result = future.result();
> ```

Thus, your code should rather look like

```
myClass mcl;

QFuture<float> f1 = QtConcurrent::run(&mcl, &myClass::foo, mvec, mstring);
f1.waitForFinished();
```